# Jupyter server cannot start

Tags: python, ssl, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I am using Macbook and was running the Jupyter server fine in the past. For nearly 3 weeks I didn't use it, and now having trouble as it isn't running.

```
$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 29, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Uninstall and re-installing jupyter didn't fix it.

```
MacOS Catalina
Version 10.15.2 (19C57)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with your brew-installed openssl, try this: https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/86

That being said, I have had issues in the past where homebrew updates my python version and breaks everything, so it might be worth investigating that as well